# How to add Different Strings in A stringList in a single statement in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

I want to add 30 different strings into a stringList . I do not want to add `AList.Items.Add` 30 times. Nor do i want to keep the strings in an array and run a loop. I was thinking may be i could write a single `AList.Add` ( not in a loop) where the strings to be added were seperated by a Delimiter . 
e.g. 
   `AList.Add('Data1' + <Delim>  + 'Data2' ...)`

How to do that ? 
Please note that i am just curious as to if it can be done this way. It is quite ok if not as there are better ways to accomplish this. ( keeping the strings in an array and using a loop to add data is my idea)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a procedure that does this:

```
procedure SLAddStrings(SL: TStrings; S: array of string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL.BeginUpdate;
  for i := low(S) to high(S) do
    SL.Add(S[i]);
  SL.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Try it:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  SLAddStrings(SL, ['car', 'cat', 'dog']);
```

Comment: it requires the use of a string array , i was curious if it could be done in a single add statement without any array stuff.

Comment: @Cyprus: Of course, you simply have to parse the string first.

Comment: What's important here is not that you use a solution that fits your pre-conceptions as to what the solution might be. What's important is what works efficiently. This answer, using an open array parameter is **the** solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Create a temporary `TStringList`, assign the string to its `DelimitedText` property, pass the temporary to the `AddStrings()` method of the destination `TStringList`, and then free the temporary.

```
var
  Temp: TStringList;
begin
  Temp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Temp.Delimiter := <Delim>;
    // if using a Delphi version that has StrictDelimiter available:
    // Temp.StrictDelimiter := True;
    Temp.DelimitedText := 'Data1' + <Delim> + 'Data2' ...;
    AList.AddStrings(Temp);
  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: apart from a little more memory consumption , this will be faster than the rest , i think

Answer (score 6):

Just use `DelimitedText` property. E.g. if your delimiter is set to `,` (default in TStringList) then you can write this code:

```
AList.DelimitedText := 'Data1,Data2';
```

Comment: But of course, this will remove all previous items in the list.

Comment: I do not have Delimited Text property , I am using D7

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: AList.DelimitedText := AList.DelimitedText + ',Data1,Data2');

Comment: @CyprUS: D7 has a DelimitedText property.

Comment: @The_Fox: That would work. But it is not particularly optimized.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand : Sorry, i overlooked that.

Comment: I would create a temporary `TStringList`, assign the string to its `DelimitedText` property, pass the temporary to the `AddStrings()` method of the destination `TStringList`, and then free the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TStringList.DelimitedText` property to add text, wich uses your `Delimiter` char. `TStringList` will split your text and then you can access each string separately using `strings` property;

```
program Project3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses classes;

const DATA = 'one,two,three';

var sl : TStringList;
    s : string;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create();
    try
        sl.Delimiter := ',';
        sl.DelimitedText := DATA;
        for s in sl do begin
            writeln(s);
        end;
        readln;
    finally
        sl.Free();
    end;
end.
```

and result is

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: But of course, this will remove all previous items in the list.

Comment: I do not have Delimited Text property , I am using D7.

Comment: @CyprUS You're searching in the wrong place probably, because TStringList's DelimitedText property is available in Delphi 7.

Comment: @teran : Sorry, i overlooked that.

Comment: sorry, I haven't noticed that question is about D7. Also `DelimitedText` with `Delimiter = ','` equals `CommaText` property. (don't know about D7, but both of them exist in D2007)